# Visual Studio 2022 : Unable to compile older projects that were compiled using C++20

Tags: visual-studio

My problem is, when I open an older project which was compiled in C++20, it is no longer C++20, but it has defaulted to C++14. How do I change the compiler setting in my older projects? When I open an older project, and select Properties, the C++ compiler selection does not show.

I tried opening a project that was compiled previously under C++20 using the Visual Studio IDE.